# Add file (as attachment) to existing email

Tags: files, email, mutt

Is there a way to add a file to an existing email with mutt?
It is an archived (i.e. old) email and I’d like to add a pdf to it for reference.

Of course, it’s possible to forward / resend it to myself and add the attachment, but that would change the sender / date of the message.

I know this is not what email is for, but is it possible? I didn’t find any option to “attach file to an existing message” in the reference: the `-a` option seems to be for composing new email only.

Answer (score 1):

With <kbd>ESC-e</kbd>, create a copy of the mail to edit (the command is `resend-message`).

Add the attachment (either from the editor or from the attachment view before sending).

Then, instead of sending the email, postpone it. It will go into the postponed folder, with the attachment, from where you can move it to the desired folder.

Note: I also tried with <kbd>e</kbd> (`edit`) where you can edit any message without creating a new copy, but the new attachmant won't get encoded in the edited message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using your method, I can add the attachment, but the date and time is changed to the time I save the new message.